# Social discrimination commentary in the Kite Runner

Tags: symbolism, the-kite-runner, khaled-hosseini

I have just recently got in touch with such an inspiring book called *The Kite Runner* by Khaled Hosseini. I was quite astonished by how the idea of racism and religious discrimination is stressed throughout the book, and the way it presented its metaphor and symbolism was exhilarating. As I'm a Muslim myself, I understand the difficulties on a personal level, brothers fighting against brothers. HORRIFIC!

I would like to understand, from a literary point of view, how Hosseini uses emotion, symbolism and other linguistic/figurative features to highlight the social groups that are silenced and marginalized in this novel. If anyone educated in this book can help me understand how Hosseini uses such tremendous techniques, it would really FULFIL my inner curiosity.